# How do I set default meta value by post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type, meta-value

I'm trying to set a meta variable depending on what custom post type is set but can't get my code to work.  This is the function in the plugin that sets the metabox after the plugin has added it to the edit page:

```
    function nd_options_metabox_post_header_img()
{
    // $post is already set, and contains an object: the WordPress post
    global $post;
    $nd_options_values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

    $nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img', true );
    if (empty($nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img)) {
  $nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img = "https://mysite/wp-content/uploads/default.jpg";
}
```

THis works perfectly so if any post has no value in that field ie it already exists it adds this default. What I tried to add was this:

```
    function nd_options_metabox_post_header_img()
{
    // $post is already set, and contains an object: the WordPress post
    global $post;
    $nd_options_values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

    $nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img', true );

    if (empty($nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img)) {
        if ($post->post_type == 'wpbdp_listing') {
              $nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img = "https://mysite/wp-content/uploads/mypic1.jpg";} 
              elseif ($post->post_type == 'job_listing') {
              $nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img = "https://mysite/wp-content/uploads/mypic2.jpg";}
              elseif ($post->post_type == 'wplp_link') {
              $nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img = "https://mysite/wp-content/uploads/mypic3.jpg";}
              elseif ($post->post_type == 'forum' || $post->post_type == 'topic' || $post->post_type == 'reply') {
              $nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img = "https://mysite/wp-content/uploads/mypic4.jpg";}              else {
              $nd_options_meta_box_post_header_img = "https://mysite/wp-content/uploads/default.jpg";} 
              }
}
```

I also tried setting a variable instead of using $post->post_type - I tried $my_post_type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) and just $my_post_type = get_post_type(), same result.

This crashes the site.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?